# The size of $\sigma$-field generated by finite sets

Tags: measure-theory

If we have a sequence of sets $F_i$ $i=1,2,...,k$ and $F_i \subset F_{i+1}$. what is the size of the $\sigma$-field, $\sigma(F_i, i=1,2,..,k)$? I guess the size is $2^{2^{k}-1}$ but I can't prove it. How can I prove this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming inclusions are proper, I think we would actually have exactly $2^k$ sets in our $\sigma$-algebra (the empty set being included). Since $F_i\subset F_{i+1}$, we could just as well take $F_1$ and $F_{i+1}\backslash F_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,k-1$ to be our generators. This gives us $k$ disjoint sets, and the $\sigma$-algebra generated by disjoint sets consists simply of unions of said sets. There are $2^k$ choices for subsets of these $k$ generators.